# access entityManager in XML RPC web API

Tags: zend-framework2, xml-rpc, entitymanager

Hello Stackoverflow Community.

I am currently developing a XML-RPc Server with Zend Framework 2.
I have a ServiceController which is responsible for creating the Server

```
class ServiceController extends AbstractActionController{

    public function xmlAction()
    {
        $this->handleXML();
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        return $response;
    }

    private function handleXML()
    {
        $xmlServer = new Zend\XmlRpc\Server();
        $xmlServer->setClass('Beam\Model\service\Service', 'service');
        echo $xmlServer->handle();
    }

}
```

The ServiceClass is my Webapi

```
class Service{

    /**
     * getAvailablePackages
     *
     * getAvailablePackages is responsible for returning all packages which reference a given licensenumber
     *
     * @param string $licenseNumber
     * @return String
     */
    public function getAvailablePackages($licenseNumber){

        //need to access the entityManager
        $em = $this->getServiceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'); 

        return "testresponse";
    }

}
```

The XML RPC server works fine. I can call the getAvailablePackages method with a client and i get "testrespons" as a response.
However the problem is, that i would like to select some data from my database in the getAvailablePackages but i'm not sure how to access the entityManager in a non Controller class.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem ? Thankx for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution would be to have a factory.

```
<?php
namespace ....;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class ServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService (ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new Service ($serviceLocator->get ('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'));
    }
}
```

thus, you would be able to have an access to Entity manager.

Comment: Thankx for replying so quickly. Seems pretty straightforward. One more question. How would i then access the Entity Manager in my Service class ?

Comment: You have EntityManager as a parameter in the constructor. I suppose `$this->getEntityManager()` and `$this->setEntityManager()` or a mere private member. How you go about it inside your class is totally up to you.

Comment: Do i have to map the new Faktory to my Service Class in the module class ?